# Extrude 2D Colored Image in Three.js

Tags: javascript, svg, three.js, 3d, rendering

I've looked for resources online, but I have not seen a way to extrude a colored image in Three.js. I'm trying to create something like a Minecraft item where the image is used to then create an extruded geometry. An example would be: https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/File:BowSpinning3.gif

I've tried looking at this resource: https://muffinman.io/three-js-extrude-svg-path/ but this only extrudes uncolored SVGs.

```
loader.load('./textures/diamondbleu.svg', function (data) {

  // Group we'll use for all SVG paths
  const svgGroup = new THREE.Group();
  // When importing SVGs paths are inverted on Y axis
  // it happens in the process of mapping from 2d to 3d coordinate system
  svgGroup.scale.y *= -1;

  const material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial();

  // Loop through all of the parsed paths
  data.paths.forEach((path, i) => {
    const shapes = path.toShapes(true);

    // Each path has array of shapes
    shapes.forEach((shape, j) => {
      // Finally we can take each shape and extrude it
      const geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(shape, {
        depth: 20,
        bevelEnabled: false
      });

      // Create a mesh and add it to the group
      const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

      svgGroup.add(mesh);
    });
  });

  // Get group's size
  const box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(svgGroup);
  const size = new THREE.Vector3();
  box.getSize(size);

  const yOffset = size.y / -2;
  const xOffset = size.x / -2;

  // Offset all of group's elements, to center them
  svgGroup.children.forEach(item => {
    item.position.x = xOffset;
    item.position.y = yOffset;
  });

  svgGroup.position.set(0, blockSize*75, 0);

  // Finally we add svg group to the scene
  scene.add(svgGroup);
})
```

Is there a way to modify the code to allow for colored SVGs? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `SVGLoader` that's available in the [`"examples/jsm/loaders/"`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/jsm/loaders/SVGLoader.js) folder.

The docs have outlined [how to generate SVGs in 3D space](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#examples/en/loaders/SVGLoader), it looks like your code sample is missing the part where the `paths` loop makes a new material and assigns a color for each `path`:

```
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {
    color: path.color,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide,
    depthWrite: false
} );
```

Your code seems to create a single `LambertMaterial` with no colors assigned, and no lights. Lambert materials need lights to be illuminated, whereas `BasicMaterial` just shows the color without need of lights.

Look [at the code in this demo](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_svg) for another example. Instead of using `path.color`, this demo finds the color by accessing `path.userData.style.fill`. I think you'll want the latter approach, depending on your SVG file.